# why history.push produce 2 objects in history stack, react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, back-button, browser-history

I am using 'react-router-dom' library.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
    window.lib_history = useHistory();

    return /*doesnt matter*/;
}
```

From console I push some page, but in browser history and in library history 2 object appeared.

```
/*in console*/

console.log(window.history.length, lib_history.length); // return 11  10 <--it is okay

lib_history.push('/page2'); // redirect successfully

console.log(window.history.length, lib_history.length); // return 13  12 < -- why not 12  11??
```

And as a main problem - user have to click browser back button 2 times to get previous page.
Where should I look for problem?

Comment: What is `window.lib_history`? Are you simply trying to create a global history object?

Comment: useHistory() gives an instance, which i used to navigate as in docs: [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Comment: Sorry, the question wasn't what `history` was, but rather, why you are saving an instance of it (from the hook). Generally if you needed to do something like create a global history object you'd follow [this setup](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Router/history-object).

Answer (score 0):

There was an Iframe in my project which spoiled history stack of whole browser tab.
Thanks for hints about setting up history, it was helpful also.